# Pass different variables to different Stages

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a Code Pipeline setup via the AWS CDK that monitors a main branch. When a push is made to the main branch the Code Pipeline is triggered. My Pipeline contains two stages, UAT and Prod. A push to the main branch will result in the changes being made to the UAT environment, and then a manual approval is needed to push the changes to the production environment.

E.G.:

```
        pipeline.AddStage(new JournalAppStage(this, "uat", new Amazon.CDK.StageProps {
          Env = new Environment {
            Account = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UAT_ACCOUNT"),
            Region = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UAT_REGION")
          }
        }));
        
        pipeline.AddStage(new JournalAppStage(this, "prod", new Amazon.CDK.StageProps {
          Env = new Environment {
            Account = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROD_ACCOUNT"),
            Region = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROD_REGION")
          }
        }), new AddStageOpts {
          StackSteps = new [] { new StackSteps {
            Stack = JournalAppStage.journalStack,
            ChangeSet = new [] {
              new ManualApprovalStep("ChangeSetApproval"),
            }
          }}
        });
```

My question is, how can I pass different variables to each of these stages? As an example, I have an API gateway that can only be accessed via the VPC Endpoint, however this endpoint ID is different in UAT and Prod, so I would like to be able to pass in a different Value to each stage.

Comment: Just pass them as arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how to do this?